# how to know if a contact is added, changed or deleted in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, contentobserver

I am working on an application whereby I need to listen to changes in native contacts database like if a contact is edited/deleted or a new contact is added.

I know I can achieve this with the help of contentobservers. However I found it pretty strange that android SDK does not provide a way to know which contact is added/deleted or which one is changed. This results in a lot of manual work like traversing through entire contact list and checking which one is changed.

I want to know if there is any better way of achieving this. I know this question would have been asked many times but I want to know why Android SDK does not have such a mechanism in place?

Thanks.

Comment: see `android.database.ContentObserver` + `android.database.CursorJoiner`, uncle google will help you on how to use it

Answer (score 2):

[This interesting thread from the early days of Android](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/oayhLnhmQGQ/OYqkBEIm644J) indicates that the `ContentObserver` did use to tell you what had changed, but it was too difficult to provide that information. It goes on to state why (at least at that time) re-querying was thought to be good enough and safer.

Answer (score 0):

This service class provide the wake up call from the changes of contacts add, update, delete operations from the background. I don't know whether this piece of code is useful for you.

```
public class ContactOberverService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "ContactOberverService";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public class MyContactContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public MyContactContentObserver() {
            super(null);
            Log.d(":-> Service Called","in construcrtor ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.d(":-> Service Called","In onChange");
            ContactsDbOprations.getAllContacts();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                true, new MyContactContentObserver());
    }
}
```